# Setting alpha transparency at a listView android

Tags: java, android, listview, alpha-transparency

Hi i would like to set some transparency to my listview ,  i've alredy see some examples of that , but all of than were a 100% transparent .

as this topic :
How to make the ListView transparent in android?

As Jacky mentioned, setting attributes for list view will do the job.

```
android:background="#00000000"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

But in my case i just want to make it half transparent , some sort of alpha 50  and stuff.
My goal here is that the user could see the background of the UI through listview but also see the background of my listView with a bit of transparecy.

How can i achieve that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that alpha transparency is an expensive operation since it involves read back from memory to blend the colors, you should probably think about disabling alpha on less capable devices

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I recall correctly, first two digits from `#00000000` are for alpha channel.

Something like `#80XXXXXX` will be 50% transparency.

You can refer [Color State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) for further explanation.

Comment: ok . I achive my goal here , but the problem is that when i scroll the list  it gets dark , probably because android is setting the background to black before load the views . How can i manage that?

Comment: Post another question, with sources.

Comment: already find out ,  just need to set this:android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

Answer (score 5):

You can programitically set the transparency level of the UI element. 
yourUIElement.setAlpha(0.5) makes 50% transparent. 
The setAlpha method takes the value from 0 to 1 
0 : Completely Transparent 
1 : Completely Opaque.

Answer (score 3):

Colors are expressed in ARGB color space, so #336699CC is:

0x33 transparency
0x66 red component
0x99 green component
0xcc blue component